# Removing windows 10 and install Linux mint 19.0

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, linux-mint

when i install linux mint 19.0 show error like this..

> Force UEFI Installation? This machines's firmware has started this
>   installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there maybe existing
>   operating systems already installed using BIOS compatibility mode, If
>   you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode,it might be difficult to
>   reboot into any BIOS-mode operating system.

I was trying this installation many times. But i could not supposed to do this. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've been informed about is the limitation of some operating systems (well on the PC platform technically it's just one, namely Windows) to be bootable in just the specific configuration they've been installed to.

For example the Windows bootloader is not able (without manually applying some quirks) to boot a system from a drive that's accessed in AHCI mode, if the drive was accessed using IDE when installing the system.

In the same vain Windows is very picky about the combination of boot mode and partitioning scheme: If the system boots via legacy BIOS the Windows bootloader forcefully expects to boot from a drive that's partitioned in the lecagy BIOS/DOS/MBR partitioning scheme, and vice versa if it's booted via UEFI it wants to see the system on a drive using the GPT partitioning scheme, that was introduced with UEFI.

UEFI booting works *only* with GPT. However GPT is backwards compatible to legacy BIOS by means of a MBR stub.

Linux never has a problem booting into "foreign" territory. As long as the root partition with the PID=1 process (by default `/sbin/init`) becomes available before the kernel (or the initramfs) wants to execute it, Linux is a happy camper. Hence modern Linux bootloaders and distributions will ask you, which partitioning scheme to use, because, quite frankly, it doesn't matter *to Linux*. Of course if you want to boot your system through UEFI it has to be GPT.

So you booted the Ubuntu installer through UEFI. The installer detects that there's been some OS already installed on a BIOS/DOS/MBR partitioning scheme. Some OS don't like it, if their boot mode changes. Some however are perfectly fine with it. And the Ubuntu installer is capable of *converting* a preexisting BIOS/DOS/MBR partitioning scheme into GPT, so it asks you, if you want to do that conversion.

Your intention seems to be, to completely wipe what's on the system and replace it with Ubuntu. In that case it doesn't really matter. Just go ahead and install in UEFI mode. When asked about which drive to install to opt to erase the disk

[image: Ubuntu target modes]